# Why does setDuration not work inside QSequentialAnimationGroup?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qvariantanimation

I have two QVariantAnimation stuffed into a QSequentialAnimationGroup and I'm trying to invert one of them. I tried to do it like this

```
self.animation_1 = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
self.animation_2 = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()

self.animation_1.setDirection(QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Backward)
self.animation_2.setDirection(QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Forward)

self.group = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self)
self.group.addAnimation(self.animation_1)
self.group.addAnimation(self.animation_2)
```

But it didn’t work. I tried so

```
self.group.setDirection(QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Backward)
```

But the whole animation is inverted. and I only need to invert one of them.
I tried to do this by referring to the index

```
self.group.animationAt(0).setDirection(QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Backward)
```

Zero reactions. I also tried to do it like this

```
self.group.animationAt(self.group.indexOfAnimation(animation_1)).setDirection(QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Backward)
```

It still didn't help.

How to do it?

My code

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        block = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        block.setObjectName(u"block")
        block.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 300))
        self.block_but = QtWidgets.QWidget(block)
        self.block_but.setObjectName(u"block_but")
        self.block_but.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 20, 111, 111))
        move_blur_button_lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.block_but)
        move_blur_button_lay.setObjectName(u"move_blur_button_lay")
        self.menu_arr = []

        radio = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.block_but)
        radio.setText('click me')
        radio.setObjectName("mv_radio_but")
        radio.pressed.connect(self.menu_animation)
        move_blur_button_lay.addWidget(radio)
        for x in range(2):
            menu = QtWidgets.QWidget(block)
            menu.resize(50, 60)
            menu._expand = False
            self.menu_arr.append(menu)
        self.menu_arr[0].setStyleSheet("""background:#ff0""")

        self.animation = []
        for i in range(2):
            menuAnimation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation()
            menuAnimation.setDuration(500)
            menuAnimation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutQuart)
            menuAnimation.setStartValue(QtCore.QPoint(-20, 10))
            menuAnimation.setEndValue(QtCore.QPoint(0, 10))
            self.animation.append(menuAnimation)
        self.group = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self)

    def menu_animation(self):
        for c in range(2):
            pos1 = QtCore.QPoint(0, 0)
            pos2 = QtCore.QPoint(100, 0)
            self.animation[c].setStartValue(pos1)
            self.animation[c].setEndValue(pos2)
            self.animation[c].setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
            self.animation[c].valueChanged.connect(
                lambda value, val=c: self.fun(value, val)
            )
        #self.animation[0].setDirection(QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Backward)
        #self.animation[1].setDirection(QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Forward)

        self.animation[0].setStartValue(pos1) 
        self.animation[0].setEndValue(pos2) 
        self.animation[1].setStartValue(pos2) 
        self.animation[1].setEndValue(pos1)




        self.group.addAnimation(self.animation[0])
        self.group.addAnimation(self.animation[1])
        self.group.start()

    def fun(self, value, val=""):
        self.menu_arr[val].move(value.x(), 0)


StyleSheet = """
QWidget QWidget,
QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
QWidget,
QWidget QWidget QWidget,
QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#fff;
color:#000;
}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = Main()
    w.resize(640, 570)  
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What I want to get

[image]

Comment: Explain yourself better, what do you mean invest only one? How do you want the yellow and white rectangle to behave when you press the QRadioButton? Does the execution of the animation depend on the status of the QRadioButton?

Comment: @eyllanesc now `QRadioButton` just starts the animation. I will use `if self.sender().objectName() == '1' : self.animation[0].setDirection(QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Backward)` later, now I want to understand how to work with `setDirection()`. I could just use `self.animation[0].setStartValue(pos1) self.animation[0].setEndValue(pos2) self.animation[1].setStartValue(pos2) self.animation[1].setEndValue(pos1)` for this, but I have to write twice as much. which is not very suitable for me

Comment: mmm I do not understand you. Do not explain your attempts at solution but your real objective. For example, currently the green square moves from left to right, when this ends the white square does the same. In your case, what do you want to happen when 1) the QRadioButton is not checked and 2) the QRadioButton is checked?

Comment: @eyllanesc My goal is to learn how to invert animation using functions setDirection. It is much easier than writing setStartValue and setEndValue. And the problem is that setDirection does not work if the animation is inside QSequentialAnimationGroup. I need the first block to move from left to right and the second from right to left. When I wrote the last question, they told me that there was too much unnecessary in my code. so I cut it.

Comment: 1) Learning is the consequence for SO, it cannot be the main objective since in SO we are dedicated to specific questions. 2) The first block from and to what point should it move? Be concrete, that is to say something like: "I want to move the TopLeft point of the block from the point P(0, 0) to P(100, 0)". The same points to block 2. Do both have to move at the same time or first block one and then loop 2? 3) The code you provide generates what the .gif shows so if that code generates what you want then I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to shorten the code from `self.animation[0].setStartValue(pos1) self.animation[0].setEndValue(pos2) self.animation[1].setStartValue(pos2) self.animation[1].setEndValue(pos1)` to `self.animation[0].setDirection(QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Backward) self.animation[1].setDirection(QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Forward)`. Isn’t it natural for the programmer to try to maximize the code for the best work?

Comment: I do not understand you, please be specific, I have asked you something very timely, if you do not provide what I have asked you then I will continue my way.

Comment: @eyllanesc I already changed the code and added gif. Yes, the code works as I need. But I want to use setDirection for this. It is very useful to be able to invert some of the animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not documented how the direction of QSequentialAnimationGroup affects the directions of the animations, but if [the source code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/animation/qsequentialanimationgroup.cpp?h=5.14.1#n408) is reviewed:

```cpp
void QSequentialAnimationGroup::updateDirection(QAbstractAnimation::Direction direction)
{
    Q_D(QSequentialAnimationGroup);
    // we need to update the direction of the current animation
    if (state() != Stopped && d->currentAnimation)
        d->currentAnimation->setDirection(direction);
}
```

It is noted that the address of the QSequentialAnimationGroup is applied to the animations. The solution would be to override that method and override that behavior but unfortunately that method cannot be accessed from python.

A workaround would be to implement the logic by connecting the `clicked` signal to the `start()` method of the first animation and the `finished` signal of the first animation to the `start()` method of the second animation.

```py
class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        block = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        block.setMinimumSize(300, 300)
        self.block_but = QtWidgets.QWidget(block)
        self.block_but.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 20, 111, 111))

        radio = QtWidgets.QPushButton("click me", self.block_but)
        move_blur_button_lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.block_but)
        move_blur_button_lay.addWidget(radio)

        first_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(block)
        first_widget.resize(50, 60)
        first_widget.setStyleSheet("""background:#ff0""")

        second_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(block)
        second_widget.resize(50, 60)

        pos1 = QtCore.QPoint(0, 0)
        pos2 = QtCore.QPoint(100, 0)

        self.first_animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            self,
            duration=500,
            easingCurve=QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutQuart,
            startValue=pos1,
            endValue=pos2,
            direction=QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Forward,
            valueChanged=first_widget.move,
        )

        self.second_animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            self,
            duration=500,
            easingCurve=QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutQuart,
            startValue=pos1,
            endValue=pos2,
            direction=QtCore.QVariantAnimation.Backward,
            valueChanged=second_widget.move,
        )

        radio.clicked.connect(self.first_animation.start)
        self.first_animation.finished.connect(self.second_animation.start)
```